# How can i add Multiple Markers on Google Map using SQL as a Database and JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jsp-tags, java-server

i have succesfully added multiple markers on google map using static data

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
 </script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var delay = 100;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.0000, 78.0000);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  function geocodeAddress(address, next) {
    geocoder.geocode({address:address}, function (results,status)
      { 
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var p = results[0].geometry.location;
          var lat=p.lat();
          var lng=p.lng();
          createMarker(address,lat,lng);
        }
        else {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
            nextAddress--;
            delay++;
          } else {
                        }   
        }
        next();
      }
    );
  }
 function createMarker(add,lat,lng) {
   var contentString = add;
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
     map: map,
           });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
     infowindow.open(map,marker);
   });

   bounds.extend(marker.position);

 }
  var locations = [
           'New Delhi, India',
           'Mumbai, India',
           'Bangaluru, Karnataka, India',
           'Hyderabad, Ahemdabad, India',
           'Gurgaon, Haryana, India',
           'Cannaught Place, New Delhi, India',
           'Bandra, Mumbai, India',
           'Nainital, Uttranchal, India',
           'Guwahati, India',
           'West Bengal, India',
           'Jammu, India',
           'Kanyakumari, India',
           'Kerala, India',
           'Himachal Pradesh, India',
           'Shillong, India',
           'Chandigarh, India',
           'Dwarka, New Delhi, India',
           'Pune, India',
           'Indore, India',
           'Orissa, India',
           'Shimla, India',
           'Gujarat, India'
  ];
  var nextAddress = 0;
  function theNext() {
    if (nextAddress < locations.length) {
      setTimeout('geocodeAddress("'+locations[nextAddress]+'",theNext)', delay);
      nextAddress++;
    } else {
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  }
  theNext();

</script>
```

Now i want to add multiple markers on google map but want to retrive all the values in locations from SQL database. 
i have tried to pass resultset as a array to JavaScript. 
but i can only call initMap() method only once a click. so not multiple markers are showing on Map. Only one marker is showing at a time not Multiple.
and also i dont want to show this markers on any onclick method. i have also used onload method but resultset.next() not retrieving throughly all values of database.

Every help would be appreciated.

Note : Please sugges only how to add markers using values which are stored in Database. Not static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah.. here i got my mistake.. i am creating Markers but not holding it. so for that i have created one array of markers.. and pushed all markers in that.. because of that i am holding every marker i am creating using database..

here my all working code goes..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import = "javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>    
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Google Maps APIs</title>

        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <style>
            html,
            body {
                height: 200px;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="initMap2();">


        <sql:setDataSource
            var="myDS"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mess"
            user="root" password=""
            />

        <sql:query var="listUsers" dataSource="${myDS}">
            SELECT * FROM latlang;
        </sql:query>

        <div align="center">
            <select id="messname">
                <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUsers.rows}">
                    <option><c:out value="${user.messname}" /></option1>
                    </c:forEach>
            </select>
            <select id="lat">
                <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUsers.rows}">
                    <option><c:out value="${user.lat}" /></option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
            <select id="lang">
                <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUsers.rows}">
                    <option><c:out value="${user.lang}" /></option2>
                    </c:forEach>

            </select>

            <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUsers.rows}">

                <button><a onclick="showMarkers();">${user.messname}</a></button>
                </c:forEach>  

        </div>               
        <script>
        </script>
        <sql:query var="result" dataSource="${myDS}" >

            SELECT * from latlang;
        </sql:query>
        <script>


            var map;
      var markers = [];

      function initMap() {
          
          var mrks = [
            <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                    ['<c:out value="${row.messname}" />',
                <c:out value="${row.lat}" />,
                <c:out value="${row.lang}" />,
                    ],
            </c:forEach>];

        //var haightAshbury = {lat: 37.769, lng: -122.446};

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: {lat: 18.5204, lng: 73.8567},
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        // This event listener will call addMarker() when the map is clicked.
          
        // Adds a marker at the center of the map.
        for(var i=0; i<mrks.length; i++)
        {   
                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(mrks[i][1], mrks[i][2]);
                addMarker(pos);
        }
     }

      // Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
      function addMarker(location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          map: map
        });
        markers.push(marker);
      }

      // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
      function setMapOnAll(map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          markers[i].setMap(map);
        }
      }

      // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
      

      // Shows any markers currently in the array.
      function showMarkers() {
        setMapOnAll(map);
      }

      // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
        </script>

        <p><td>  </td></p>

<input type="text" id="searchvalue">

<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click" onclick="">        
<%-- //>--%>

<div id="map" style="height:200px; width:200px"></div>
<p>


    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBN1fnarI5qrCYI7gS6ksuX3L7jHGTq2MY&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

thanks for helping..!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have list with markers data named `result` if not then create a list and full it with the data.

*Tip maybe you need* `List<Marker> markers; // full with data from database request.setAttribute("result",markers) // set markers in request scope`

You can create an js array using markers' info from database by JSTL#foreach:

```
var markers = [
 <c:forEach var="marker" items="${result}">
    ['<c:out value="${marker.title}" />', // wrapped single quotes if string
      <c:out value="${marker.lat}" />,
      <c:out value="${marker.lng}" />,
    ],
 </c:forEach>   ];
```

And now you can traverse it to make dynamically markers:

```
function initialize() {
   /*your map definitions here*/

  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
     var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: position,
         map: map,
         title: markers[i][0],
         icon: image
     });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
    
       return function () {
            //if clicked
       }
     })(marker, i));
  }
}
```

Also you can look at a full example [Goole Maps with JSP/JSTL](https://github.com/gurkan0791/EmlakUygulama/blob/master/web/index.jsp)

Comment: please help me with List. I have 3 columns in my database. Name,Lat,Lang. how can i get all that values in array. and also how can i pass that array to function. please tell me. actually i have tried to store in 2D Array. But its not working

Comment: @AmitGandole Firstly, create Marker class with name, lat, lng variables and a list ArrayList<Marker>. While pulling the data from database with while loop `while(resultset.next())` create new marker and add to list for every step of the loop. `list.add(new Marker(name,lat,lng))`. Finally, add the list to request scope. request.setAttribute("result",list); Then you can access the list easily using JSTL lib. Don't forget to add JSTL lib your project.

Comment: Thanks for this. But whatever you are suggested to write var markers = [
 <c:forEach var="marker" items="${result}">
    ['<c:out value="${marker.title}" />', // wrapped single quotes if string
      <c:out value="${marker.lat}" />,
      <c:out value="${marker.lng}" />,
    ],
 </c:forEach>   ];   is not working. we cant write jstl inside script. please if you can give me working code then it ll be better. i also you code on github but that is also not working on me as you have written jstl inside script. it is not working.

Comment: @AmitGandole scripts codes must be in the jsp page not separate js file. If you push your project github I maybe fix the problem.

Comment: yeah.. actually u got me.. i m writing script in another .js file. i will gt it on github asap please help me if possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480444/for-multiple-markers-only-last-entry-of-database-is-showing-on-map-how-can-i-ad?noredirect=1#comment85964477_49480444

Comment: try this one sir. i have added what u said. now its showing only last entry of marker

Comment: @AmitGandole your code works well check [plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/VbsjYwf9StIztPBdVywN?p=preview)