# for multiple Markers only Last Entry of database is showing on Map. how can i add multiple marker on map using this.?

Tags: jsp, multidimensional-array, maps, markers

Here is my code. i have used jsp and mysql with jstl. i also tried using php but same happening.

```html
 function Marker12() {
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        var markers = [
           <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                       ['<c:out value="${row.messname}" />',
                         <c:out value="${row.lat}" />,
                         <c:out value="${row.lang}" />,
                       ],
            </c:forEach>   ];  
      //var totmark=[];
var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(18, 74),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

                alert(markers[0][1]);
                var i;
                for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
         var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]});
        
    }
```

so what is missing in my script? what is and where is overwritten? i m not getting plz help.

Comment: Seems like this line "for( i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {" is your issue; the '1' should be the length of the markers array.

Comment: no, i by mistakenly posted that. i am using markers.length there.

Comment: i have edited that. checkout now

Comment: Seems ok - add the "markers.length" to the alert to confirm it is not 1.

Comment: its showing 4. as my db all entries are 4. but i think markers are overwriting and showing only last entry. not getting how to get over it

Comment: Looks ok - so I'd check the actual lat/lngs to verify they are not coincident (right on top of each other) and within view (not half way across world hiding).  Sorry I couldn't be of much help.